# Bad request on user signup using passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Whenever I try to create a new user by posting the next content via Postman:

```
{
    "username": "username",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

I get a `Bad Request` message.

I'm setting up my API with: `express`, `mongoose` and `passportjs` as this:

File: `models/user.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
UserSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
  this.password = hash;
  next();
});

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
UserSchema.methods.isValidPassword = async function(password) {
  await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

File: `config/passport.js`

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const JWTStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('./env');

passport.use(
  new JWTStrategy(
    {
      secretOrKey: JWT_SECRET,
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    },
    async (token, done) => {
      try {
        return done(null, token.user);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    },
  ),
);

passport.use(
  'signup',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.create({ email, password });
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    },
  ),
);

passport.use(
  'login',
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'auth/not-found' });
        }

        const validPassword = await user.isValidPassword(password);
        if (!validPassword) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'auth/wrong-password' });
        }

        return done(null, user, { message: 'auth/logged-in' });
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```

File: `router/auth.js`

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('../config/env');

router.post(
  '/signup',
  passport.authenticate('signup', { session: false }),
  async (req, res) => {
    return res.send({
      message: 'signup/success',
      user: req.user,
    });
  },
);

router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  passport.authenticate('login', async (err, user) => {
    try {
      if (err || !user) {
        const error = new Error('error/occurred');
        return next(error);
      }

      req.login(user, { session: false }, async error => {
        if (error) {
          return next(error);
        }

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
        const body = { _id: user._id, email: user.email };
        const token = jwt.sign({ user: body }, JWT_SECRET);

        return res.send({ token });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return next(error);
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

File: `config/express.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const { NODE_ENV } = require('./env');
const routes = require('../router');

require('../config/passport');

const app = express();

let morganFormat = 'dev';
if (NODE_ENV === 'production') morganFormat = 'combined';

app.use(
  morgan(morganFormat, {
    skip: (req, res) => res.statusCode < 400,
    stream: process.stderr,
  }),
);

app.use(
  morgan(morganFormat, {
    skip: (req, res) => res.statusCode >= 400,
    stream: process.stdout,
  }),
);

app.use(compression());
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));
app.use('/api', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this message appearing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you send your email in the username field and check once? as I believe mongoose expect email inside username field. It is weird but yea

Comment: Please try to boil this down to a minimal reproducible example. Based on just the code you've shared it's not really possible to tell with certainty what is going wrong. Please remove things that don't affect the Bad Request response. To try and help a bit, a Bad Request means there's an error somewhere in the Routing layer. Seeing the actual code or postman details for the request you're making will help too.

Comment: A couple of other observations, you're using `methodOverride`, which according to their docs must be used before any middleware that checks the method type, so using it after cors and helmet might be a misconfiguration. Also, you're posting JSON data, but I don't see you using body-parser to parse the JSON into an object.

Comment: @JonChurch your got it. You comment pointed out the errors and now it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @JonChurch Could you post this as an answer to give you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Bad Request` typically  means there's an error somewhere in the Routing layer.

You're using [`methodOverride`](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override), which according to their docs must be used before any middleware that checks the method type, so using it after cors and helmet might be a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use app.use(passport.initialize()); it will initialize passport js you haven't initialize passport in your code in `config/express.js.`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have no [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json) middleware.
Try adding `app.use(express.json())` to `config/express.js`